# Speedily create a random array

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, vectorization, blas

I have a for-loop:

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++) a[i] = rand()
```

But that's too slow, and BLAS/vDSP/vecLib/etc are at my disposal. I'm looking for a function to create an array of random numbers; it seems like it should be included.

Besides the name for this function, I would also appreciate a some good vDSP/vecLib/etc documentation. I've found [some documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009465), but it's not good -- just general descriptions of the functions.

Comment: Is it ok to assume you want unsigned values?

Comment: Yes, that's okay. I'll take any random array -- I can easily transform that with BLAS/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`dlarnv`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/db/d9c/dlarnv_8f_source.html) does what you describe.  It populates a `double` array with random (uniform or normal) values, and it is included in vecLib.

Comment: And there's no mentions of the functions included anywhere in Apple's docs.

Answer (score 0):

Fast and well-distributed random number generators are useful for many purposes, so I'm sure you can find some great ones out there.  I would start by looking at the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister), and in particular implementations that are optimized for SIMD, like [this](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/SFMT/).

The next step in speed would come from GPU or DSP based algorithms, but I'm not aware of any in the public domain at the moment.